# How should I arrange the entries vertically in spfx custom form?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, custom, react, edit-form

I have an SPFx custom form, and in a multi-value text field, I want to enter a small note. The note should automatically include my name and the date, like this:

David MÜLLER am 23.5.2023: Hello StackExchange!

David MÜLLER am 23.5.2023: This is my Note

David Müller am 23.5.2023: Hello World

[image: concept]

The Problem:
I understand that you initially thought it would be easy and I could code it in 10 minutes. However, you're facing an issue where the notes are not fitting properly, even though you're using user.displayName and new Date().toLocaleString(): notes\n to retrieve the name and date. Currently, it looks like this:

MÜLLER David am 23.5.2023: MÜLLER David am 23.5.2023: test
test2

[image: athis does my code...]

Some code:

```
const { notes } = this.state;

const newNote = `${user.displayName} - ${new Date().toLocaleDateString('de-DE')}: ${notes}\n`;

const itemProperties = {
  
  'Notiz': newNote,
  
}
```

Any help?